# What does it mean for a function to have a method?

Tags: go

I'm seeing the following type definition:

```
type Getter func(ctx *context.T, key string) (Ticket, error)
```

And the following method defined on it:

```
func (g Getter) GetData(ctx *context.T, path ...string) (data []byte, err error) {
    …
}
```

I'm also seeing the following variable definition:

```
var Client Getter = func(ctx *context.T, key string) (Ticket, error) {
    return …
}
```

where:

```
type Ticket interface {
    …
}
```

What'll happen with this code exactly?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `type Getter func()` is, not a [_type alias_](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations), but a [_type definition_](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions).

Comment: Functions are values, just like `2` or `"two"`. You can "attach" methods to your own (non-function) types. Types are not separated into function and non-function type groups. You can add methods to function types too, and you can call them the same way you can call methods of values of other types.

Comment: Without more details, your question is likely going to be difficult to answer. However, there are situations where it makes sense to declare a method on a type whose underlying type is some function type. See https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandlerFunc for an example.

Comment: A [working example](https://go.dev/play/p/EQ9y-8Eumlq) might be easier to understand.

Comment: Tracing through more of the code, I see that one of the methods eventually calls `g`.

Comment: Would the following declaration have made more sense to you: `type Getter struct { f func(ctx *context.T, key string) (Ticket, error) }`? If so, because that struct has a single field, you might as well declare `Getter` as in your question.

Comment: The code in the question is from  [this file](https://github.com/grailbio/base/blob/66da27c47f7939b01dbe170ceef9e42af646426f/security/ticket/helper.go).  The Getter type has methods that call a lower-level function to get a ticket.  To make the ticket function swappable in tests,  the ticket function is specified as the receiver.  The code could have been written as `type Getter struct { fn func(ctx *context.T, key string) (Ticket, error) }` with calls to the receiver replaced with `x.fn(c, k)`  The `var Client` statement declares the default Getter to use in the application.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** It won't compile because `Cannot use 'func() (MyData, error) { return nil, nil }' (type func() (MyData, error)) as the type Getter`. In other words, `MyGetter` does not match the type of `Getter`. Here's a [go playground link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/E4xeB5Jimgv).

There are a couple of things going on here:

1. You're creating a type called `Getter`. Any value that fulfills this `Getter` type must be a function with zero input parameters and zero output parameters (keep this in mind for a second).
2. Go has first-class functions which means they can be assigned to variables, passed to parameters of other functions, or in this case methods can be added to a type whose underlying type is a function.
3. Lastly, you're trying to assign a function with the signature `func() (MyData, error)` to the type `Getter` which is where you're getting the compile error I mentioned in the tl;dr. This compile error is because your type `Getter` specifies that any value of this type must be a function with zero input parameters and zero return parameters. You're trying to assign a function that does have return parameters.

Comment: `Getter` is a type, *not* a type alias. Also, types don't "implement" type aliases, nor do they implement types. Functions are values, and as such, can be used as values of a function type with the same signature, but that is not an "implements" relationship, it's just a type-value relationship.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the verbiage corrections. Edited.